# MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra - How to lookup multiple rows in Matrix

Tags: matrix-multiplication, matrix-indexing, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to do a sparse matrix multiplication using MathDotNet Numerics. Input:

```cs
Matrix<float> mat  // dense matrix of size n x k, where n is large and k ~ 10
int[] index        // int[] of length l ~ 10, e.g. { 7, 13, 11, ... }
```

So I'd like to look up multiple columns, i.e. something like "`mat[index]`", which would be of shape `l x k`.

**Could anyone tell me how I could do this?**

(do I iterate through the `index` and stack the rows or is there a better way?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the stacking solution:

```cs
Matrix<T> lookup = CreateMatrix.DenseOfRowVectors(indices.Select(i => matrix.Row(i)));
```

It feels like there might be a better way that doesn't require a new memory allocation.